# Display gridview base on multiple values

Tags: gridview, sqldatasource

I am looking to pull my data to a grid view base on one parameters which is an ID; the tricky part is, this ID might content a multiple IDs. 
In sql, I can write something like below.

```
Select * from table1 where ID in ('ID123', 'ID234', 'ID456').
```

How do I do that with sqldatasource. Note: I already pull a multiple values into lblID
Below is what the structure that I have.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [talbe1] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="ID" ControlID="lblID" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```